# How to return to normal mode by pressing ESC only once

Tags: normal-mode, insert-mode

I have been using vim for a short time, so I may not know a lot, please forgive me.

There is a problem with my vim. It cannot enter normal mode from insert mode by pressing `esc/ctrl-[` only once, but needs to press `esc/ctrl-[` twice.

When I first press `esc/ctrl-[` show command remind me I entered `^[`.
I have tried to turn off all the plugins I use, but it doesn't solve.

There is my vimrc file:

```
syntax enable

set showcmd
set relativenumber
set shiftwidth=4 tabstop=8
set notimeout
set autowrite

call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
Plug 'ycm-core/YouCompleteMe'
Plug 'raimondi/delimitmate'

call plug#end()
```

System: Ubuntu 20.04, terminal vim, local

Comment: The first thing you should try is running with sane defaults in place of your vimrc. Add the Vim flag `--clean` when you launch. Next you could turn off your three plugins then turn them on/off one at a time to see if any are the cause. Basically you want to debug your vimrc. Here's a full treatment of that topic: [How do I debug my vimrc file?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003)  Welcome to Vi&Vim SE.

Comment: @BLayer Thank u!

Comment: No problem. If you narrow things down but don't fully solve the problem [edit](https://vi.stackexchange.com/posts/30993/edit) your question and add whatever new information you've found.

Comment: Does `:imap <ESC>` show any mappings that might be defined starting with the ESC key?

Comment: @filbranden yes, that's strange.

Comment: @BreezyMain By "yes", do you mean you did find such a mapping? Would you care to expand on what the mapping was? Like Ben mentioned on his answer, run it with `:verbose` to see where it was defined... Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

As sussed out in the comments, you have mappings that begin with `<esc>` somewhere (and the surprise indicates you didn’t ask for them). You can use `:verbose imap <esc>` to find out where the mappings are coming from; in general, mappings with a prefix cause a delay whenever the prefix is entered, as vim has to distinguish between the prefix starting a mapping and not. In other words, vim has to wait for the keypress after the prefix (or a fixed amount of time; there are options to control it) to know what to do next.

I suggest getting rid of the mappings if possible. If you can identify what they are/where they come from, I can provide suggestions on how to remove them.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for answering the question. Although no body found what the problem is, I still be thank to you.

The reason is `timeout` and `ttimeout` is off as the same time. It caused my vim waiting a operation forever. The solution is open the `timeout`. If you want to let your vim to be faster, you can turn on `ttimeout` and set `ttimeoutlen` to a low value. my is 100.

Comment: Good catch! For some reason I guess we didn't think of `ttimeout`, which surely explains this... Also note that `ttimeout` (and a `ttimeoutlen` of 100) is set in `defaults.vim`, consider sourcing that file from your vimrc. See `:help defaults.vim` for more details on how to do that.